# Code Sign Error: duplicate certificate

Tags: xcode, certificate, xcode4.3, provisioning

I let my iOS membership expire and now I am trying to get everything hooked up again.

I cannot get rid of this error "Code Sign error: Certificate identity 'iPhone Developer: xxxx xxxx (NUMBERS)' appears more than once in the keychain. The codesign tool requires there only be one."

I looked in Keychain Access. found the 'expired' certs and deleted them. Right now I only see a developer cert and a distribution cert. I have restarted the computer, quit xcode, quit keychain but cannot figure out where the duplicate is.

I logged in to the portal and the certs are all renewed. In keychain access the cert its complaining about has an expy of 2013 now.

Do I have to erase everything and start again?

Any other thoughts of where to look?

Answer (score 0):

Check the provisioning profiles stored in ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/. You probably have an old provisioning profile which contains your expired certificate.

Xcode has a 'helpful' behavior of extracting and installing all the certificates found in all the provisioning profiles for the current user onto the default keychain. You've got to delete the old invalid profiles or it will continue to install the associated (expired) certificates.

Also, I've seen Xcode continue to install old certificates even after you've cleaned up the Provisioning Profiles directory. This was fixed for me by simply rebooting.

A handy tool for making sense of your .mobileprovision files is [QuickLook for MobileProvision](http://www.macmation.com/blog/2012/07/quicklook-plugin-for-mobileprovision-mountain-lion-ready/).